# PHPfpm and Nginx not working in Docker with Supervisord

Tags: php, nginx, docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I am running 2 processes inside a docker container an Nginx server and PHP-FPM with supervisord but it just keep exiting with status 1 (unexpected)

Here are the logs

```
2016-12-09 21:37:35,529 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-12-09 21:37:35,596 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-12-09 21:37:35,598 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-12-09 21:37:36,602 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
2016-12-09 21:37:36,606 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 8
2016-12-09 21:37:36,671 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:36,722 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:37,727 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 20
2016-12-09 21:37:37,737 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 21
2016-12-09 21:37:37,801 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:37,848 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:39,856 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 33
2016-12-09 21:37:39,863 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 34
2016-12-09 21:37:39,917 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:39,997 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:43,007 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 46
2016-12-09 21:37:43,011 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 47
2016-12-09 21:37:43,071 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:43,072 INFO gave up: nginx entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2016-12-09 21:37:43,130 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 21:37:43,132 INFO gave up: php-fpm entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I have added daemon off to both Nginx and PHPFPM but it still does not work 
Here is the Nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
daemon off;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  120;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Also i have ran following command to turn daemon off inside PHP-FPM

```
RUN sed -i 's/;daemonize = yes/daemonize = no/g' /usr/local/php-7.0.12/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

Here is my supervisord.conf file

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command: service nginx start

[program:php-fpm]
command: service php-fpm start

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://localhost:8091

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[inet_http_server]
port = 8091
```

Can someone guide me how to run these processes inside supervisord on docker container?

**Docker Container Logs**

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-12-09 22:06:43,939 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-12-09 22:06:43,992 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-12-09 22:06:43,994 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-12-09 22:06:44,999 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 8
2016-12-09 22:06:45,003 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 9
2016-12-09 22:06:45,065 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:45,124 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:46,131 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 21
2016-12-09 22:06:46,138 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 22
2016-12-09 22:06:46,223 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:46,275 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:48,282 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 34
2016-12-09 22:06:48,288 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 35
2016-12-09 22:06:48,346 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:48,426 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:51,435 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 47
2016-12-09 22:06:51,443 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 48
2016-12-09 22:06:51,526 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:51,528 INFO gave up: nginx entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2016-12-09 22:06:51,555 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-09 22:06:52,558 INFO gave up: php-fpm entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: can you check and post logs of docker using docker logs <container-hash> ?

Comment: @PenkeySuresh I have added container logs as well

Comment: That's because both services daemonize. To daemonize, they need to perform an exit. Supervisor detects that as an error and starts them again. Solution is to run nginx non-daemonized and leave php-fpm as it is because php-fpm is a supervisor of its own.

Comment: @N.B. I have already posted config above showing i have written daemon off inside nginx configuration and even if i leave php-fom it still exits with status 1

Comment: You **do not** need to run `php-fpm` via supervisor. Can you start both programs normally, without supervisor? If yes, then the problem is in process control. Ensure that both programs fail when you don't use supervisor, which will give you further options to explore what's happening. If both work without it, then you know it's because of process control. Both programs are made not to fail, there's no reason to supervise them really. It's like adding water to water to make it more "water". If `php-fpm` were to fail, the same reasoning could apply to `supervisord` - why wouldn't it fail?

Comment: @N.B. I used supervisor because i need to run more then one process and i cannot use multiple CMD commands inside Dockerfile 
The PHP-fpm just returns startoing PHP fpm when  launched. Supervisord make sure that container remains alive

Comment: Try what I suggested first to determine that both services can start in a regular way. If they fail, at least you know it's not because of supervisor. If they start, then you know it IS because of supervisor.

Comment: @N.B. I tried both with CMD ["nginx"] and it works and i tried with PHPFPM as well both works but container just quits incase of phpfpm 
I think i am doing something wrong incase of supervisord

Comment: There you go, both programs perform an `exit` and supervisord tries to restart them, ending in an endless loop. I told you that you don't need supervisord, there's no real reason why you'd require it with those two programs but hey - you can persist and spend more time on it. Supervisord is useful for different types of programs which aren't designed to be daemons/services, and nginx / php-fpm are designed to be that. I don't know exact reason why you need it with Docker, but hey, at least we know it's to do with process control.

Comment: but how can i run these 2 programs at a same time in dockerfile without supervisord? I cannot use more then one CMD in dockerfile so i am unable to understand how to run both simultaneously in a dockerfile

Comment: I haven't used docker, but I checked its docs and they use `RUN` to start services. I really haven't played with it so far, but it seems quite odd that you could only use `CMD` and then supervisor to start services, if it were silly like that I doubt anyone would even use it.

Answer (score -1):

### Let's talk a bit about Docker and supervisord

#### First of all - No need to use Nginx and php-fpm in 1 container.

That's pretty bad practice. You should not do like this. You should use 1 container for Nginx and 1 container for php-fpm.
For example my Nginx default.conf is something like that:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.php;
    server_name race_lab.local;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found   off;
        access_log      off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow           all;
        log_not_found   off;
        access_log      off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny            all;
    }
}
```

As you can see here I am using `fastcgi_pass php:9000;`. That's because in my `docker-compose.yml` i have service with name 'php' and exposed 9000 port.

#### supervisor(d)

As you know, supervisord works on the following principle: it creates its own process and what is specified in the config will be created by a subprocess. This is done so that supervisord can control these processes.

Example of my .conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm7.4 --nodaemonize
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

If we are talking about `supervisord` with `php-fpm` and `nginx` the only thing i want to mention is PATH to your `PHP-FPM` binary file.

#### php-fpm - choose wisely

At the start i tried to start `supervisord` like this:
`/etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm start`

And that's is not how it works. I tried to use `php7.4-fpm -n` (`-n` is like `--nodaemonize`) and that works. Why? Lets fall into the container and search some information about php-fpm.
`docker ps` -> `docker exec -ti <container> /bin/bash` or simple `docker exec -ti <container> /bin/bash -c "which php7.4-fpm"` Response: `/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4` That's all. You need to choose right binary for supervisor daemon.

So, to conclude: `php-fpm` uses a lot of binaries and configs and you should know about what are they doing (That's hard and pretty stupid, but we can't do anything with it :( ). If you want use supervisord with something with daemon - just search a binaries with option that allow you to turn off this!

Comment: `That's pretty bad practice` - reference please.

Comment: No one ever packs multiple services into the same container. I can't find any reference to this rule, but it's a canon known to all developers

there is a solution called docker-compose. And it exists for a reason. The whole docker network based on IPTABLES (probably in the past) allows to split containers into several pieces. 
The problem arises precisely when it is necessary, for example, to scale a project. Or put some loadbalancers 

And if all this also happens using k8s, the containers simply can't work properly.

Comment: In general - this is a waste of resources, because the same k8s controls the number of replicas. This is the same as shoving a database into each replica (for example redis HA for each replica is very stupid)

Comment: `This is the same as shoving a database into each replica` - well no, it is not. It is _very common_ to use phpfpm with a socket with nginx, suggesting this is a bad practice warrants some evidence to backup that opinion. In any event I see I've unintentionally touched a nerve, please keep your answer and comments factual/objective :).

Comment: No, it's okay. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: It's not bad practice, it's just not yours. It's become increasingly common to bundle services like this to reduce unnecessary complication. Perhaps it is required in your setup (though I doubt it), but there are many where this would increase cost and complication without any tangible gain.