# Unable to run Openfire with supervisord in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openfire, supervisord

I am using supervisord to run openfire inside a docker container but supervisord says the process is exited but actually it is running when i open the exposed port i see an openfire dashboard although the supervisord dashboard shows its exited

Here are my container logs

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.3.1-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-12-10 02:44:28,562 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-12-10 02:44:28,628 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-12-10 02:44:28,630 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-12-10 02:44:29,635 INFO spawned: 'openfire' with pid 7
2016-12-10 02:44:30,734 INFO success: openfire entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-12-10 02:44:30,792 INFO exited: openfire (exit status 0; expected)
2016-12-10 02:46:04,355 INFO spawned: 'openfire' with pid 56
2016-12-10 02:46:04,410 INFO exited: openfire (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-12-10 02:46:05,415 INFO spawned: 'openfire' with pid 65
2016-12-10 02:46:05,464 INFO exited: openfire (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Here is my supervisord conf file

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:openfire]
command=/etc/init.d/openfire start

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://localhost:8090

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[inet_http_server]
port = 8090
```

The same thing is happening with me when i run Nginx and PHP-FPM but in that case supervisord does not run it as seen here [PHPfpm and Nginx not working in Docker with Supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077039/phpfpm-and-nginx-not-working-in-docker-with-supervisord)

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here? I am new to docker so i might be missing some key points here.

Answer (score 0):

What you start with supervisor must run in foreground and not daemonize itself (see [docs](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html)).
Instead, change the command to (modifying folders accordingly):

```
command=/usr/bin/java -server -DopenfireHome=/usr/share/openfire -Dopenfire.lib.dir=/usr/share/openfire/lib -classpath /usr/share/openfire/lib/startup.jar -jar /usr/share/openfire/lib/startup.jar
```