# Running httpd and php-fpm under supervisord process in docker does not work

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, supervisord

I have this set up where I'm trying to run httpd and php-fpm in a docker container via a supervisord process.

My supervisord.conf is like so:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true


[program:httpd]
command=httpd -DFOREGROUND
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Here is my Dockerfile Entrypoint for the command:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

Notice above that I'm not running supervisord in foreground mode. Does it need to run in the foreground?

I bring up the entire app with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

In my dockerfile, the CMD is set to supervisord and I feed it the supervisord.conf file. The problem is, when I define both httpd and php-fpm in the supervisord.conf file, I find that supervisor fails to run the httpd program but is able to run php-fpm. I get this error:

```
2022-12-15 22:35:23,437 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2022-12-15 22:35:23,439 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2022-12-15 22:35:24,443 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 10
2022-12-15 22:35:24,445 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 11
httpd (pid 11) already running
2022-12-15 22:35:24,537 INFO exited: httpd (exit status 0; not expected)
2022-12-15 22:35:25,540 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 14
2022-12-15 22:35:25,540 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
httpd (pid 11) already running
2022-12-15 22:35:25,628 INFO exited: httpd (exit status 0; not expected)
2022-12-15 22:35:27,632 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 15
httpd (pid 11) already running
2022-12-15 22:35:27,716 INFO exited: httpd (exit status 0; not expected)
2022-12-15 22:35:30,721 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 16
httpd (pid 11) already running
2022-12-15 22:35:30,802 INFO exited: httpd (exit status 0; not expected)
2022-12-15 22:35:31,803 INFO gave up: httpd entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

But when I remove the php-fpm configuration from supervisord.conf, the app work fine. For some reason these two apps can't work together? The strange thing is that this used to work for me but all of a sudden after some code changes, it's not working anymore. I don't get much in the way of error messages. I just know that httpd will not start, but php-fpm does. Any idea what is causing this?

Another strange thing is that this will work like 1/10 times. Why is it intermittent?

And I know that for Docker it's good to have one process per container, but for my specific use-case, I need these two on the same container.

I tried all kinds of different options for the supervisord config, like setting the priority to be lower and turning off autorestat or setting the expected error code to be 1, with no change.

I read from [PHPfpm and Nginx not working in Docker with Supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077039/phpfpm-and-nginx-not-working-in-docker-with-supervisord#comment69362566_41077039) that apps that daemonize tell supervisord they they've exited, and thus supervisord counts this as the app failing. But as you can see in my config, I've ran the programs in the foreground, unless I have the syntax wrong. It's the same syntax I've used before though and it works.